# Use Microsoft Azure java SDK Resource Management API or Service Management API?

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I am able to successfully connect to resource management API using Java SDK.

Once the connection is successful, can I continue with ARM to list resources at subscription level like os images, locations, regions etc using ARM? Or do I need to again shift to Service Mgmt API? Is every operation doable with the new ARM API?

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment for @juvchan, I knew you want to list os images and vm images for creating a VM in Azure Java SDK.

As @juvchan said, the ARM APIs are different from ASM APIs for Azure Virtual Machine. You can refer to the VM REST APIs documemts for ARM(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163647.aspx) and ASM(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157206.aspx) to know the differences.

So you can use the Azure Service Management API includes operations for manageing the Virtual Machines in your subscription to implement your needs.  And for authenticating Service Management Requests, you can refer to the docment https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx and the blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can use ARM API to list resources at subscription level.

Please see [List the resources in a subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790567.aspx)

For the difference between ARM and Service Management API, you can refer to this reference from Microsoft.

[Understanding Resource Manager deployment and classic deployment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/#classic-deployment-characteristics)

Comment: My actual requirement is to create a VM. So I was trying to list os images and vm images(snapshots of vm) so that user can select from list of available images. I was not able to fetch this info from ARM API. The call VirtualMachineImageResourceList list = computeMgmtClient.getVirtualMachineExtensionImagesOperations().listTypes(VirtualMachineExtensionImageListTypesParameters) is expecting typeParametes. Passing null to this call returns bad url request error. What is the exact way to call available vm and os images? Or what is the right input for TypeParameters?